# Yii2: yii\db\Exception 42000 on quotation(') search

Tags: yii2

Hi i have problem with Yii2 search model.
when user try to search with quotation (for example it's) this exeption Thrown:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's%' )' at line 1 
The SQL being executed was: 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` `t` WHERE id in (SELECT user_id from user_profile WHERE nickname like '%it's%' )
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(900): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(388): yii\db\Command->queryInternal('fetchColumn', 0)
#2 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Query.php(393): yii\db\Command->queryScalar()
#3 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\ActiveQuery.php(334): yii\db\Query->queryScalar('COUNT(*)', NULL)
#4 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Query.php(300): yii\db\ActiveQuery->queryScalar('COUNT(*)', NULL)
#5 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\data\ActiveDataProvider.php(165): yii\db\Query->count('*', NULL)
#6 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\data\BaseDataProvider.php(147): yii\data\ActiveDataProvider->prepareTotalCount()
#7 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(130): yii\data\BaseDataProvider->getTotalCount()
#8 \app\modules\post\views\default\search.php(47): yii\base\Component->__get('totalCount')
#9 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(325): require('...')
#10 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(247): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('...', Array)
#11 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(149): yii\base\View->renderFile('...', Array, Object(app\modules\post\controllers\DefaultController))
#12 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(378): yii\base\View->render('search', Array, Object(app\modules\post\controllers\DefaultController))
#13 \app\modules\post\controllers\DefaultController.php(94): yii\base\Controller->render('search', Array)
#14 [internal function]: app\modules\post\controllers\DefaultController->actionSearch(''"', NULL, NULL)
#15 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(154): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#17 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(454): yii\base\Controller->runAction('search', Array)
#18 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(87): yii\base\Module->runAction('post/default/se...', Array)
#19 \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#20 \app\web\index.php(16): yii\base\Application->run()
#21 {main}
```

Yii2 can't escape parameters automatic ? Do I have to do it menualy ?

thanks.

Comment: How did you write the query?

Comment: the info is not enough show your model and controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for it's 
You hava a wrong quote sequence

try using escape for inner quotes

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` `t` WHERE id in (SELECT user_id 
                                             from user_profile 
                                             WHERE nickname like '%it\'s%' )
```

or use double quote fo like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` `t` WHERE id in (SELECT user_id 
                                             from user_profile 
                                             WHERE nickname like ("%it's%" )
```